# How to copy a csv file using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import, copy

I need to import a csv in my database.
I created a function in sql that does the import:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION import_match_csv(filename varchar(500), username varchar(500)) RETURNS VOID AS $$
   BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE match_import (....));

    COPY match_import FROM 'filename' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

    INSERT ....

    DROP TABLE match_import;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling the function writing in the psql prompt

```
 SELECT * FROM import_match_csv('/Users/benny/Desktop/match.csv', 'benny');
```

I get the error:

> Error: ERROR:  could not open file "filename" for reading: No such file or directory
>   HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "COPY match_import FROM 'filename' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
>   PL/pgSQL function import_match_csv(character varying,character varying) line 33 at SQL statement

Comment: Drop the single quotes around filename in your COPY statement, it's just a string literal at the moment.

Comment: @OTTA If I drop the single quotes I get a sintax error at filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL, since `COPY` doesn't support parameters:

```
EXECUTE format(
           'COPY match_import FROM %L (FORMAT ''csv'', DELIMITER '','', HEADER)',
           filename
        );
```